# Adding time with structure construction in C

Tags: c, if-statement, struct

I've just started C, and I have a task to add 1minute and 30sec to the entered date which consists of year month day hours minutes seconds.

So, I've used struct construction as it is one of the requirements. 
However, everything looks good until the many cases I have to take care of. 
For example I have to change everything if the entered date is 2014/12/31 23:58:30 or 2014/2/28 23:59:00 .. The easiest way is to check it with if statements but I think there should be another way, instead of writing a massive number of `if` statements, for every case I want to take care of. Could you please tell me if there is another clearer way of doing so.

```
struct{
 int day;
 int month;
 int year;
 }a;
struct{
 int hours;
 int minutes;
 int seconds;
 }b;
```

Thought this way might make a little bit more if statements. Also another requirement is to add 0 if the month for example is entered as 3, the output should be 03.. Anyway it seems I cannot escape from the "phone number" if statements. Thanks for the answers and time spent!!

Comment: 1) Please show us what you've tried so far. 2) you can cosider using `switch` case, but then again, without seeing your code, this may not be a good advice.

Comment: A cleaner way would be to use functions like `incrementMonth(int currentMonth)`,`incrementMinute(int currentMinute)` with several `if`s in them. Provide a shortened version of your code for giving us an idea about how your code is structured.

Comment: Also, note that there are [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)`, [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year), [daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), [changes to daylight savings time](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/chile-abolishes-dst-2015.html), [time zone changes](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/samoa-dateline.html) and other fun problems.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `<time.h>`? If the struct you're creating is a `struct tm`, you can convert it to a `time_t`, add 90 seconds, and convert back to a struct from there.

Comment: "123123 if statements"??? Please rephrase this into something that doesn't look like a text message on your cell-phone.

Comment: @barakmanos: I believe that simply means "many".

Comment: @BillLynch: I agree with you, but it makes the question look like... you know...

Comment: If allowed to use time functions, after filling `struct tm tm;` use `tm.tm_sec += 90; mktime(&tm);`.  `mktime()` will do the needed adjustments.

Comment: Bill, yeah thats why I posted it as a question here. All the cases with leap years, seconds, hours..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's assume that you don't care about all of the really hard parts about time. Things like: [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year), [daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), [changes to daylight savings time](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/chile-abolishes-dst-2015.html), and [time zone changes](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/samoa-dateline.html).

If you don't, then let's consider this problem like we are building a custom adding operator.

```
struct time {
    unsigned year;
    unsigned month;
    unsigned day;
    unsigned hour;
    unsigned minute;
    unsigned second;
};

struct time time_add(struct time date, struct time delta) {
    date.year   += delta.year;
    date.month  += delta.month;
    date.day    += delta.day;
    date.hour   += delta.hour;
    date.minute += delta.minute;
    date.second += delta.second;

    // Implement corrections
    while (date.second >= 60) {
        date.second -= 60;
        date.minute += 1;
    }
    while (date.minute >= 60) {
        date.minute -= 60;
        date.hour += 1;
    }
    while (date.hour >= 24) {
        date.hour -= 24;
        date.day += 1;
    }
    // and so on..

    return date;
}
```

Using this method, you should be able to significantly cut down on the number of cases that you have to deal with.

Comment: Could add `int` overflow and extreme date range to the don't case list.

Answer (score 0):

if you want some way to abbreviate this (or some general way to add numbers in strange, variable, numeration basis, like for example the old pence, shilling and pounds system), try to put the things in an array and the numbering bases for each digit in another, fixed array, so you can do something like:

```
int basis[] = {
    100, /* hundreds of a second in a second */
    60,  /* secs in a minute */
    60,  /* mins in an hour */
    12,  /* hours in a cycle(AM/PM) */
    2,   /* cycles in a day */
    30,  /* days, but be careful, not all months have 30 days */
    12,  /* months */
    100, /* years in a century */
    0,   /* centuries, and sentinel to stop. */
};

int carry = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i; i++) { /* sum array a and b into c */
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i] + carry; /* sum digit i */
    carry = c[i] / basis[i]; /* determine carry, can be abreviated */
    c[i] %= basis[i]; /* determine final value, can be abreviated */
} /* for */
c[i] = a[i] + b[i] + carry;  /* finally, centuries, not based */
```